# Is it possible to select bone through the object? (Python)

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the parent bone data from the object?

```
class BIND_FUNC(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "bind.function"
    bl_label = "BIND"

    def execute(self, context):
        context = bpy.context
        target = context.active_object
        
        obs = [o for o in context.selected_objects
            if o.type == 'MESH'
            and o is not target]
        for ob in obs:
            mod = ob.modifiers.new("SurfaceDeform", 'SURFACE_DEFORM')
            mod.target = target
            bpy.ops.object.surfacedeform_bind(
            {"object" : ob},
            modifier=mod.name
            )
            
            self.report({'INFO'}, f"This is {self.bl_idname}")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CLEAR_TRANS(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "clear.function"
    bl_label = "CLEAR"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        context = bpy.context
        target = context.active_bone
          
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'POSE')
        bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action="SELECT")
        bpy.ops.pose.transforms_clear()
        bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action="DESELECT")
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

        self.report({'INFO'}, f"This is {self.bl_idname}")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

This is the code that I'm working on rn. I want to combine them together but only click on the object and not the bone.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best method due to un-reliability of it when object name and object data name are miss-matching when it comes to searching the armature in another class, but I use it and seems to work fine, and allows to use it regardless of whether the selected object is a mesh or the armature itself

However when it comes to selecting a bone in the viewport the only way I could think is to switch to pose mode briefly to allow for a bone to be selected by the user and use that selection for the name of the bone that is needed and switch back to the needed mode after selection

from this bone data can be accessed  with `ParentArmature.pose.bones["Bonename"]`

```
        ParentArmature = None
        ContextObject = None

        if (context.active_object.type == "MESH") and (context.active_object.find_armature() is not None):
            ParentArmature = context.active_object.find_armature()
            ContextObject = context.active_object.name
        if (context.active_object.type == "ARMATURE") and (context.active_object is not None):
            ParentArmature = bpy.data.objects[context.active_object.name]
```